# How do I enable or disable scripts based on a condition?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

This seems like it would be fairly simple. But I have no idea.

For example, if the user was an Admin, extra functionality would be available. If the user was not, some actions would no longer be possible because the code was not generated.

Do I actually put Ruby inside the scripts and end the filename with .erb?

Comment: Are you talking about loading certain *JavaScript* scripts conditionally, or Ruby? If the latter, where does JS come into this?

Comment: Let's specifically say that I have a list that is sortable via jQuery UI. How would I would I enable or disable the sortable list depending on the users's credentials. What is the best practice for this?

Answer (score 0):

OK so from your comment above, I now get a feel for what you want.

It's a question of which side of the server to do things on. User credentials, of course, are handled server-side. Therefore, this would need to be communicated to the client, i.e. JS.

How you do that very much depends on your set-up. One conceivable model would be that your JS calls, via AJAX, a server-side script that reports back on whether the user is an admin or normal user. Perhaps the server-side script simply returns a string - `user` or `admin`.

Based on the response, you could load the admin-only functionality - i.e. JS scripts - that you need.

You could do this manually or, more easily, use one of the many JS loaders out there. AMD (asynchronous module definition) loads are very much the zeitgeist at the mo, so look into something like require.js or curl.js. A simply (non-AMD) option would be LABS.js.